# LaTeX: newcommand not working?

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

Image attached:
I recently tried using the `newcommand` but like always it often doesn't render the `\int` or the integration sign, I know this becuase if I remove it from the body, everything seems fine.
[image]

Comment: Be careful with these. As a sort of fluke, new commands defined in higher answers affect the TeX on lower answers too. Although rare, this causes problems if multiple users create new commands for the same things.

Comment: @mixedmath to be exact about the situation:there was no answers above me, OP didn't added any newcommands; maybe when you see the situation remains same **[here:link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086620/cauchy-principal-value-integral-calculation)**

Comment: Since it seems to be reproducing inconsistently, do you know which browser (and what version) you were using when it occurred?

Comment: @alexwlchan i always use chrome(maybe latest)

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be working on my end...

```
$$\newcommand{\I}[0]{\infty}
\newcommand{\irf}[4]{\int_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4} {\rm d} x}
\irf{-\I}{+\I}{x+\sin x}{x(x^2+4i-4)^2}$$
```

$$\newcommand{\I}[0]{\infty}
\newcommand{\irf}[4]{\int_{#1}^{#2} \frac{#3}{#4} {\rm d} x}
\irf{-\I}{+\I}{x+\sin x}{x(x^2+4i-4)^2}$$

Comment: but why doesn't mine

Comment: I have no idea. I even tried putting this code into [your answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086620/cauchy-principal-value-integral-calculation/1086691#1086691) and it rendered correctly.

Comment: seems like the problem is specific to me only happened to me a few weeks ago too

Comment: I you put this code into your answer yourself, does the preview render correctly?

Comment: currently it seems working, but as I have attached the image, sometimes it does frustate me

Comment: Happy New Year btw